# Azure Virtual disk vs Azure vhdx drive

Tags: azure, azure-vm

On Virtual machine screen of Azure 
[image]
whether the virtaul disk gets created OR vhdx disk gets created?

Answer (score 1):

It will be in VHD format.

If you have a VHDx disk that you wish to upload and use in Azure you must first convert it to VHD. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/prepare-for-upload-vhd-image